# completely delete all of the pending tasks of a specific celery queue in python

Tags: python, celery

I dynamically declare a queue with `celery_app.control.add_consumer("new-queue")`.

How do I fully empty this queue called `new-queue` from python, after queueing a bunch of tasks to it?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463916/7376511 suggests to use the following:

```
import celery.bin.amqp
amqp = celery.bin.amqp.amqp(app = celery_app)
amqp.run('queue.purge', 'name_of_your_queue')
```

however this does not work anymore, it raises `Context.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app'`, and passing it as a positional argument returns `TypeError: 'Celery' object is not iterable`.

`celery_app.control.purge` doesn't take a queue name either.

Comment: Celery CLI can purge particular queue. I suggest you find that code and use it in your script...